# Force Tumblr to use http link instead of https

Tags: html, http, https, tumblr

I'm aware that it is promoted to use Secure sockets and `HTTPS` should be used instead of simple `HTTP`. But the website I developed is hosted on a server, that has definitions for http only. Https would pop out a 404, that is why I want to use `http://` instead of `https://`.

I am currently editing the theme for Tumblr blog of mine, I'm using this code,

```
<div class="each-object">
   <h4>
     <a href="http://www.aceinternationals.com" 
     target="_blank">2. Ace Internationals</a>
   </h4>
</div>
```

But when I save it, Tumblr changes the `http://` to `https://` which would always cause a `404`.

[image]

Have a look at the code highlighted and the URL (bottom left corner). They're both different.

What should I do, to over come this in Tumblr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to over come this in Tumblr as the server converts this to `https`. One trick that I came up with was to use goo.gl and shorten the link with `http://`.

I converted the link to goo.gl shortened link and then used it in the template. It worked then!

I wonder when Tumblr would allow `http://` links.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the need for `http://` when editing the theme?
Because from what I've tested, Tumblr does not convert the actual link to `https://` after you save the page. It only does so for the sake of the preview.

Comment: I can confirm this, both the preview and live page show `http://`. It may have been an intermittent issue. http://i.imgur.com/fhatQyA.png