# Tumblr using https link instead of http

Tags: http, https, tumblr

I tried to setup my blog on
http://anshulgarg.me

When I open the link, it opens normally, but after few minutes, when I refresh it, it starts to redirect it at https://anshulgarg.me

My problem is similar to this one:

[Force Tumblr to use http link instead of https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350332/force-tumblr-to-use-http-link-instead-of-https)

What should I do to use http over https on Tumblr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my browser.

I had "HTTPS Everywhere" extension installed which was forcing chrome to use HTTPS over HTTP.